# Xcode 6 iPhone simulator running in the wrong resolution

Tags: sprite-kit, ios-simulator, xcode6

I am currently working on a spritekit project for school, and the resources we've got handed out, are made for the iPhone 4s resolution. I used my physical iPad mini retina, for the previous exercises, and it seems that after I did that, the resolution of the simulator has changed to the iPad resolution.

I've asked my classmates, and teacher and none of us cannot figure out why.

Rep too low for image. When I run the iPhone simulator for the iPhone 4S, the resolution displayed is 1024x768.

Comment: I also have this issue, I'm using a Universal Storyboard and the simulator works fine with iPhone 4s, all iPads, iPhone6 & iPhone6+ but the 4 inch simulators show in letterbox.

Answer (score 0):

If closing the Simulator and Xcode doesn't fix it, try changing the simulated device type manually from the Simulator menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting iOS Simulator Window->Scale to 50%, this seems to have fixed the issue for me for almost all my simulators. Preview of iOS 6 Simulator below.

[image]